# Document the Tables columns and stored procedures used in the SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

We have hundreds of SSIS packages with in line SQL code and as well as Stored procedures. We are in process of migrating to new systems and wanted an easy way ( any tools available as well) to document all the SQL objects (tables, columns, SPs) used in the SSIS packages.

Note: These SSIS packages are deployed as file deployment not catalog deployment.

Manually extracting the information from the SSIS packages are tiresome.